# matching List in any order when mocking method behavior with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a test using Mockito that has a very strange behavior : it works in debug but fails when running normally. After some investigation, I realized it's because I am mocking methods behavior, passing a list of elements to match. But for some reason, order in the list is not always the same so it doesn't match and what I expect my mock to return is not returned, because the 2 lists are not "equals"

```
 when(mockStatusCalculatorService.calculateStatus(Arrays.asList(IN_PROGRESS, ABANDONNED,EXPIRED))).thenReturn(ConsolidatedStatus.EXPIRED);
```

In my case, order of elements to match doesn't matter. So how can I specify this when configuring my mock ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**If you have Mockito prior to version 2.1.0:**

Use the Hamcrest `containsInAnyOrder` matcher.

```
when(myMock.myMethod(argThat(containsInAnyOrder(IN_PROGRESS, ABANDONED, EXPIRED))))
    .thenReturn(myValue);
```

Thank you to @kolobok for pointing out that as from Mockito 2.1.0 (which came out after I wrote this answer), this no longer works.

**So for version 2.1.0 and above:**

add a dependency on Hamcrest, and use the `MockitoHamcrest.argThat` instead of `Mockito.argThat`

More detail on the breaking change with Mockito 2.1.0 is at https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.1.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html

Comment: yes, you're right.. one thing to note though is that casting the output of argThat into the expected type by the method seems mandatory in most cases

Comment: if I don't have Hamcrest, only mockito?

Comment: Don't think it's the best solution, but I bypassed this issue by giving multiple  when statements. If you are just trying to push a test through, it's probably the easiest way (if you have a small number of items in your collection)!

Comment: `argThat` requires `ArgumentMatcher`, but 'containsInAnyOrder' returns `Matcher`, so this doesn't work

Answer (score 33):

Adding an answer for newer versions of Mockito and Java 8

```
when(
   mock.method(argThat(t -> t.containsAll(Arrays.asList(IN_PROGRESS, ABANDONED, EXPIRED))))
).thenReturn(myValue);
```

Comment: Using `containsAll` yields false positives, since it'll also match values that have the desired values plus additional ones.  So it's not the same as "equals, ignoring order".

Comment: simple way to improve it, if you don't want to import any additional libraries, is to also compare the list sizes, it'd be: `List<ConsolidatedStatus> statuses = Arrays.asList(IN_PROGRESS, ABANDONED, EXPIRED); when(mock.method(argThat(myList -> myList.size() == statuses.size() && myList.containsAll(statuses)))
).thenReturn(myValue);` . Otherwise, if you already have any powerful dependencies with collection utils added, can just replace by their implementations, e.g. with `org.apache.commons:commons-collections4` using `myList -> CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection(myList, statuses)`

Answer (score 3):

it's actually quite simple. we need a custom matcher :

```
import org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils;
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher;
import java.util.List;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.argThat;

public class InAnyOrderListMatcher extends ArgumentMatcher<List> {

private final List expected;

public InAnyOrderListMatcher(List expected){
    this.expected=expected;
}

@Override
public boolean matches(Object actual) {

    if(actual instanceof List){

        List actualList=(List)actual;

        return CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection(expected,actualList);

    }

    return false;
}

public static List inAnyOrderListMatcherEq(List expected) {
    return argThat(new InAnyOrderListMatcher(expected));
}

}
```

And then call it in the test :

```
when(mockStatusCalculatorService.calculateStatus( inAnyOrderListMatcherEq(Arrays.asList(IN_PROGRESS, ABANDONNED,EXPIRED)))).thenReturn(ConsolidatedStatus.EXPIRED);
```

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel.  Hamcrest already has a matcher for this.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If order does not matter, change your StatusCalculator service to accept a Set instead of a Collection.  Then equals will return true regardless of order.

Better to fix your API than hack around it in your unit tests.

Comment: "Be conservative in what you do, be liberal in what you accept from others", so changing `Collection` to `Set` would require a better reason than "it makes my test easier to write"