# Mockito - ignore order when verifying a method with varargs

Tags: java, mockito, parameter-passing, verify

First of all I'll present some code:

```
    class ResourceContainerTest {

        // Normally, in beforeTest
        ResourceContainer container = mock(ResourceContainer.class);

        @Test
        public void testClearResources(){
            container.addResources("resource1");
            container.addResources("resource2");
            container.addResources("resource3");
            container.removeResources("resource3");

            // the following line should invoke 
            // container.removeResources("resource1", "resource2") 
            // or container.removeResources("resource1", "resource2"):
            container.clearResources();  

            // Now, let's verify it:
            verifyThatRemoveResourcesWasInvokedForVararg("resource1", "resource2");
        }

        private void verifyThatRemoveResourcesWasInvokedForVararg(String... resourceNameList){
            verify(container).removeResources(resourceNameList);
        }
    }
```

In this short example I want to test if `resource1` and `resource2` will be removed in one invocation of removeResources().

**The question is how can I ignore the order of vararg so the test will be passed for both `verifyThatRemoveResourcesWasInvokedForVararg("resource1", "resource2")` and `verifyThatRemoveResourcesWasInvokedForVararg("resource2", "resource1")` ?**

I've already tried an approach with `ArgumentCaptor`:

```
ArgumentCaptor<String> resNamesCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
        verify(container).removeResources(resNamesCaptor.capture());
        Assert.assertEquals(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(resourceNameList)), new HashSet<>(resNamesCaptor.getAllValues()));
```

but in this case I get an `org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations`

Any tips?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [matching List in any order when mocking method behavior with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40883990/matching-list-in-any-order-when-mocking-method-behavior-with-mockito)

Comment: `containsInAnyOrder` also works for arrays.

Comment: "I get an `org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations`" - you're certain that it actually *is* only being invoked once? That sounds like `container.removeResources()` is being called multiple times.