# Mockito - comma verify argument with comma separated list without order

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, hamcrest

My Mockito version isn't the newest -version 1.10.19

I have a method in my DAO class I want to test, for example

```
public void updateMe(String commaSeparatedAttributes)
```

It get a string as argument with comma separated list as 2,5,3

The problem is that the order of the list isn't guaranteed.

I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40883990/matching-list-in-any-order-when-mocking-method-behavior-with-mockito) with Hamcrest `containsInAnyOrder`, but this doesn't help me because the argument is a String, I tried several options (including sending ArrayList) as:

```
verify(dao).updateMe(argThat(Matchers.containsInAnyOrder("2","5,"3")));
```

This isn't compiling with error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Iterable<capture#1-of ? extends String> to String
```

**EDIT**

Also the following return NullPointerException in test

```
verify(dao).updateMe(argThat( 
new ArgumentMatcher<String>() { 
@Override 
public boolean matches(Object argument) { 
List<String> inputs = Arrays.asList(((String)argument).split(",")); 
return inputs.containsAll(Arrays.asList("2", "5", "3")); 
} 
} 
));
```

Comment: Your `updateMe` method takes a string. The matcher used in your verify expects a collection. You may be better off writing a custom matcher

Comment: @shinjw So there isn't any built in method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `updateMe` method takes a `String`. The matcher used in your verify expects a `Collection`. You may be better off writing a custom matcher.

You'll first need to break your comma separated `String` into a `List` of `String`s.

Then use `List::containsAll` with your expectations passed in.

```
verify(dao).updateMe(argThat(t -> {
    List<String> inputs = Arrays.asList(t.split(","));
    return inputs.containsAll(Arrays.asList("2", "5", "3"));
}));
```

Comment: I'm getting `The method argThat(Matcher<T>) in the type Matchers is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> t) -> {})`

Comment: Are you on JDK 7 or lower?

Comment: no, java 8, actually I have 2 arguments so I'm using your code in addition to i parameter, e.g.: `verify(dao).updateMe(i, argThat(t -> { ...`

Comment: ahh cool. did this work for you? fwiw hamcrest does have [stringContainsInOrder](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#stringContainsInOrder(java.lang.Iterable)) However, the method name and documentation seem off. I'd need to peek at the source to see what is actually being matched

Comment: `verify(dao).updateMe(ArgumentMatchers.any(), argThat(t -> ...`

if you replace i with `any()` should get you further along. also be sure to be using Mockito matcher libraries instead of hamcrest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171859/discussion-between-shinjw-and-user7294900).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found a working solution, but I decided String with comma separated values is error prone and changed DAO method signature to Set and therefore changed mockito test to check against Set is working as expected:

```
verify(dao).updateMe(new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(2,5,3)))
```

Comment: If you change the order of the values passed into your method in test, it will most likely break

Comment: @shinjw Now if I change numbers it return success for `(Arrays.asList(2,5,3)` and also `Arrays.asList(2,3,5)`

Comment: This is because HashSet does not care about ordering. Everything is fine there.